# Why Scala compile does't permit in scope method overload?

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, compilation

I have notice, that scala compiler does't permit in scope method overload.
*Scala version 2.11.12*

**Doesn't compile:**

```
val result = {
  def loop(a: String): String = ???

  def loop(i: Int): Int = ???

  ???
}
```

**Compile correctly:**

```
def loop(a: String): String = ???

def loop(i: Int): Int = ???

val result = ???
```

**Question:**

- Why it is so?
- What is the difference between have a method in scope and outside of scope?

Answer (score 1):

Overloading happens when you *call a method on an object*, it does not happen with bare function calls. So you can only define overloaded methods for a class. A block is not a class, so it can't have overloaded methods.

Your "compile correctly" code will only work if it is placed directly inside a class/object.

Comment: I think this just restates the question